# Google Apps new nav bar: where is manage this domain?

Tags: google-workspace

I've setup a new Google Apps account and it has [Google's new navigation bar](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2011/02/new-top-navigation-bar-rolling-out-for.html), which is beautiful and all, but I can't find the link for "Manage this Domain". Google says this:

> For administrator accounts only: Please note that the ‘manage this domain’ link which appears in Gmail for administrator accounts only, is no longer on the same line as your username and has moved to a lower position on the right side below the navigation bar.

I'm definitely an administrator because I can go to http://www.google.com/a/domain.com and access the control panel without logging in again.

Any ideas? Or do I just have to go the address manually now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has just moved down a little:

[image: GMail Navigation Bar]